# cx_freeze error after converting in to exe file tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

This is setup file which I am using

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os
base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\osama shakeel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\osama shakeel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl\tk8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Users\osama shakeel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl\treectrl2.4.1"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("alkhidmat.py", base=base, icon=r"C:\Users\osama shakeel\PycharmProjects\alkhidmat-project\icon.ico")]


cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Alkhidmat Management System",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"], "include_files":[r"C:\Users\osama shakeel\PycharmProjects\alkhidmat-project\icon.ico",'tcl86t.dll','tk86t.dll', 'icons2']}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Tkinter Application",
    executables = executables
    )
```

And these are the libraries which I am using.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
from csv import DictWriter, DictReader
import os
import tkinter
from TkTreectrl import *
import pandas as pd
```

And this is error which I am getting after my installation of app 
External package which I downloaded is  TkTreectrl, and another function of program is automatically creates csv file in the current directory where my(alkhidmat.py) file is present

```
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\osama
shakeel AppData\Local\Programs\Python Python37-32\lib \site
-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts _startup_.py", line 40, in run
module.runo
File "C:\Users\osama
shakeel AppData\Local\Programs\Python Python37-32\lib\site
-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 37, in run
exec(code, [name__ main__'})
File "alkhidmat.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter
ок
1
```

Comment: No I am treectrl library in that I am using list box widget

Comment: ***"how I can do ... list box which have many columns "***: `Listbox` does not support *many columns*, [edit] your question and rephrase **what you want to do**.

Comment: ***"I uploaded both codes"***: Makes it more confusing, still didn't get what you want. I can't give any useful answer, if you do not provide the information asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a great advice,D'ONT USE CX-FREEZE, use **auto-py-to-exe**. using this module, you will be ableto add an personal icon to your app, also add additional files in a very easy way.And here is the link to install it from you cmd [here](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)

Answer (score -1):

try to look in your ./lib folder (in your bulid folder) and rename "Tkinter" folder to "tkinter"